# How to load two arrays into the same tableview?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an iPhone application in which I want to add two arrays to the same tableview, ie news array and deals array, which are returned by a web service. I need to load them in the same view, ie in a tableview, as if loading from a single array. Can anybody help me in achieving this?

Comment: i m trying to go with sections,but not sure is it the way?

Comment: `NSArray *deal;` `NSArray *news;` `NSArray *yourArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:deal,news,nil];`   ist that what you mean?

Comment: You can add them in different sections or you can add them in two labels added to the cell.

Comment: @janusfidel  if i will do so how i will distinguish between the elements,i need sepaerate actions for the two ones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I soted it out like this.First take the two arrays.then merge it in to one array,and load the table view from that array.if u need seperate actions then in your didselect methode check whether the object contains in the first array then do something,else do another thing ...

Comment: But if the two arrays have different type your answer can't work

Answer (score 0):

Put code in the delegate methods which treats the `news` and `deals` arrays as two separate sections. For example, use the [`-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-SW6) to populate a first set of cells with `news` index paths and a second set of cells with `deals` index paths. Look at the [`UITableViewDataSource`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006941-CH3-DontLinkElementID_1) delegate protocol.

Comment: can u eloberate me?r u mentioning about sections?

Comment: Basically, you want to either merge the two arrays into one array, to make into one section, or treat your two arrays as separate sections. Read the `UITableViewDataSource` documentation, or any `UITableView` tutorial, which will more or less tell you the same stuff.

Comment: thanks for your comments,one doubt here is if i merge two arrays how i will distinguish between them.because i need different actions for the cells from different arrays?

Comment: @hacker i m having the exact issue right now. Did you solve this OP?How to take different actions based on the source array?